# How to position my tumblr posts side by side?

Tags: html, css, positioning, tumblr

I would like some help fixing a simple problem on my tumblr based Portfolio website.

My website is [www.ellekorhaliller.co.uk][1]

I would like to change the layout so that I can position my posts side by side. For instance instead of having just the single column of posts, I would like there to be a row of 2 posts and below that another row of two posts and so forth.

I'm sure this is a very easy matter to fix but it would be much appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction of what CSS I need to change.

Please see below for code.

Elle.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Elle Korhaliller - Fashion Stylist</title
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
    {block:Description}
        <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
    {/block:Description}
<link href='http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/DHIm5wmgi/stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



<!--

 .d8888b.  888b     d888 8888888b.  888      
d88P  Y88b 8888b   d8888 888   Y88b 888      
Y88b.      88888b.d88888 888    888 888      
 "Y888b.   888Y88888P888 888   d88P 888      
    "Y88b. 888 Y888P 888 8888888P"  888      
      "888 888  Y8P  888 888        888      
Y88b  d88P 888   "   888 888        888      
 "Y8888P"  888       888 888        88888888 

Disassemble 3.0 Theme for Tumblr by Georgia Harris
www.smpldesign.co.uk

-->

<!-- DEFAULT COLORS -->
        <meta name="color:Background" content="#ffffff"/>
        <meta name="color:Text" content="#000000"/>
        <meta name="color:Video Corner Fold" content="red">
        <meta name="font:Font" content="'BrownBold'">
        <meta name="if:Show Captions" content="0"/>
        <meta name="if:Uppercase Links" content="0">
        <meta name="if:Fade On Hover" content="0">
        <meta name="if:Show Tags on Index Page" content="0">

<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color:#ffffff;
font-family:'BrownBold', 'Muli', sans-serif;
color:#000000;
font-size:16px;
line-height:25px;
}

a { 
padding-bottom:2px;
color:#000000;
text-decoration:none;

}
img {
border: none;
border : 0;
outline:none;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;

max-width: 50%

}
a img {
outline: none;
}
iframe#tumblr_controls {  
display:none;


}


#header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom:1cm;

    z-index:5000;
    width:100%;
    top: 0px;
left:0px;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 40px;

}

#wrapper {
margin: 50px auto auto auto; 
width: 1000px;
max-width: 100%
height: auto;


}
#post {
padding:20px 0 0 0;
width:100% !important;

   position:relative !important;
   font-size:14px;

}
#post img {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;



}
#post img:hover {



}
#post embed, #post iframe {
width:100% !important;
}
#post .photoset a:first-child {

}
#post .photoset a {
display:none;
}
.title {
width:100%;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
position:fixed;
top:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
.follow {
position:fixed;
top:20px;
right:20px;
z-index:5000;
}



.archive {
position:fixed;
top:20px;
left:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
.message {
position:fixed;
bottom:20px;
left:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
.random {
position:fixed;
bottom:20px;
right:20px;
z-index:5000;
}
#toTop {
width:100%;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
z-index:5000;
position:fixed;
display:none;
bottom:20px;
cursor:pointer;
}

#page-nav {
    z-index:5000; !important
position:fixed;
margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none !important ;
    padding: 30px;
}

.player {
background:#000;
width: 1000px;
max-width: 100%
height: auto;
}
ul.chat {
list-style-type:none;
width: 1000px;
max-width: 100%
height: auto;

}
#infscr-loading {
display:none !important;
}

.corner {
top:6px;
right:40px;
position:absolute;
padding:1em 1.5em;
margin:2em auto;
color:#fff;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:4000;

}
.corner:before {
content:"";
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
border-width:0 25px 25px 0;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#fff #fff red red;
background:#fff;
display:block; width:0; /* Firefox 3.0 damage limitation */
}

.contentcolumn{
margin:auto;
width: 100%;

</style>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/4Wjm5wj58/disassemble_v3.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn();    
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $('#toTop').click(function() {
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
    }); 
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36376336-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

</head>

<body>

{block:IfUppercaseLinks}<div style="text-transform:uppercase">{/block:IfUppercaseLinks}
<div id="header">

<div class="title"><a href="/"><a style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 2px">{Title}</u></a></div>
<div class="archive"><a href="http://www.ellekorhalillerweb.tumblr.com/information">Information</a></div>
<div class="follow">{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Posts} {/block:Posts}{/block:PermalinkPage}<a href="http://www.ellekorhalillerweb.tumblr.com/contact">Contact</a></div></div>


<div class="message"><a href="http://www.ellekorhalillerweb.tumblr.com">Editorial</a></div>
<div class="random"><a href="http://www.ellekorhalillercommercial.tumblr.com">Commercial</a></div>
<div id="toTop">Back to top</div>
{block:IfUppercaseLinks}</div>{/block:IfUppercaseLinks}

<div id="wrapper">
<div class="contentcolumn">
{block:Posts}
<div id="post" 

{block:PermalinkPage}style="width:500px"{/block:PermalinkPage}
> 

{block:Text}
{block:Title}<a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a>{/block:Title}
{Body}
{/block:Text}

{block:Link}
<a href="{URL}" class="link" {Target}>{Name}</a>
{block:Description}<div class="description">{Description}</div>{/block:Description}
{/block:Link}

{block:Quote}
<a style="border:0 !important" href="{Permalink}">"{Quote}"</a>
{block:Source}
<p>&mdash; {Source}</p>
{/block:Source}
{/block:Quote}

{block:Photo}
{block:IndexPage}<a href="{Permalink}"><div style="border:none"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"  alt="{PhotoAlt}" border="0"align="center"/></div></a>{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}{LinkOpenTag}<div style="border:none"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/></div>{LinkCloseTag}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Photo}
/*Could put a center here*/
{block:Chat}
{block:Title}<h2>{Title}</h2>{/block:Title}
<ul class="chat">{block:Lines}<li class="user_{UserNumber}">{block:Label}<span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label} {Line}</li>{/block:Lines}</ul>
{/block:Chat}

{block:Video}
{block:IndexPage}<a href="{Permalink}"><div class="corner"></div></a>{/block:IndexPage}
<div id="video"> 
{Video-500}
</div>
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Video}

{block:Photoset}
{block:IndexPage}<div class="photoset">{block:Photos}<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" align="center"></a>{/block:Photos}</div>{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Photoset}

{block:Audio}
{block:AlbumArt}<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{AlbumArtURL}"></a>{/block:AlbumArt}
<div class="player">{AudioPlayerBlack}</div>
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Audio}

{block:IfShowTagsOnIndexPage}{block:IndexPage}{block:Date}{/block:Date}{/block:IndexPage}{/block:IfShowTagsOnIndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}{/block:Date}{/block:PermalinkPage}

</div></div>
{/block:Posts}

{block:NextPage}<div id="page-nav"><a href="{NextPage}">↓</a>{/block:NextPage}

</div>

</body>
</html>      



  [1]: http://www.ellekorhaliller.co.uk
```

Comment: Best way to attach code is to copy and paste into the post, THEN highlight it and click "code". I used to have that trouble when I first started out here :)

Comment: If you're having trouble attaching your code, the right thing to do is to [figure it out,](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or make a best-effort attempt and let someone else format it for you. If you just defer to the website, you've shown no effort in assembling an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), and what's worse, once your site is changed, the question loses all value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know what you are doing with HTML/CSS you should read the tumblr documentation.

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes

Specifically, you can try using the {Block:Posts[1-5]} or {Block:Even}/{Block:Odd} to divide your posts accordingly.

Hope it helps..